# dm-crypt on whole disk - cryptsetup /dev/sda?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, luks

My question is simple. Can I create a encrypt my whole disk with cryptsetup  /dev/sda? Or do I need to create the volume on seperate partition?

Edit:
I meant a situation, in which I have rootfs on this fully-encrypted disk and kernel + bootloader on seperate removable device. So according to ultrasawblade's answer I can do that, can't I?

Comment: *If you register your account and sign in, then you will be allowed to make edits to the question without waiting for approvals and leave comments under the answers.*

Answer (score 1):

You aren't required to put it on a partition.

It may make tools expecting a partition table act funny, like `palimpsest` (Disk Utility).  You'll need to remember that you don't have a partition table on this disk.  You'll also probably need to use the terminal to mount and unmount this.

---

Please note that you cannot "encrypt in place" using `cryptsetup`.  If you want to encrypt your current `/sda` and your root partition is mounted on it, the easiest thing to do will be to backup all your data, note which programs you have installed, and reinstall/restore, selecting encryption options.  Debian or the Ubuntu text installer provides these options.  Your `/boot` partition containing the actual kernel cannot be encrypted unless your boot loader supports encryption (I don't think GRUB does still).